# Gitlab Ci run one job after second job

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 2 production servers and I have 2 manual jobs, and now I want to run the second job after first.
I tried to use keys: after, needs but isn't working

Please tell me how I can run the PROD_2 job after the PROD_1 job is done and don't use `when: manual` in the second job?

```
Deploy_Build_STAGE:
  variables:
    DEPLOY_DIR: "/var/www/my_stage_app"
  environment:
    name: STAGE
    url: https://stage.example.com/
  stage: Deploy
  tags:
    - stage
  only:
    - stage
  script:
    - preparing
    - cd drupal/
    - composer install -n --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev
    - yarn install
    - yarn build --no-progress
    - copy_files -s "./" -d "$DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/"
    - generate_drush_config
    - cd $DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/web/
    - drush cr
    - drush updb -y
    - drush cim -y
    - drush updb -y
    - drush cr
    - sudo systemctl restart nginx php7.1-fpm varnish


Deploy_Build_PROD_1:
  variables:
    DEPLOY_DIR: "/var/www/my_app/"
  environment:
    name: PROD_1
    url: https://example.com/
  stage: Deploy
  when: manual
#  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - app1
  only:
    - new_prod
  script:
    - sudo systemctl stop nginx
    - preparing
    - cd drupal/
    - composer install -n --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev
    - yarn install
    - yarn build --no-progress
    - copy_files -s "./" -d "$DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/"
    - generate_drush_config
    - cd $DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/web/
    - test -d sites/default/files/ || mkdir sites/default/files/
    - drush cr
    - drush updb -y
    - drush cim -y
    - drush updb -y
    - drush cr
    - sudo systemctl restart nginx php7.1-fpm varnish




Deploy_Build_PROD_2:
  variables:
    DEPLOY_DIR: "/var/www/my_app/"
  environment:
    name: PROD_2
    url: https://example.com/
  stage: Deploy
  when: manual
  tags:
    - app2
  only:
    - new_prod
  script:
#    - sudo systemctl stop nginx
    - preparing
    - cd drupal/
    - composer install -n --prefer-dist --ignore-platform-reqs --no-dev
    - yarn install
    - yarn build --no-progress
    - copy_files -s "./" -d "$DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/"
    - generate_drush_config
    - cd $DEPLOY_DIR/public_html/web/
    - test -d sites/default/files/ || mkdir sites/default/files/
    - sudo systemctl restart nginx php7.1-fpm varnish
```

Answer (score 0):

To preserve order of executed jobs define [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stages) in your yaml, then jobs will be executed in the same order.

```yaml
stages:
  - first_stage
  - second_stage

job_1:
  stage: first_stage
...

job_2:
  stage: second_stage
...
```

or you can use default stages which execute in order:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
```